# Setting management.endpoints.web.base-path to root when server.servlet.context-path is set

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to set the base path of the actuator to / so that PCF can access it.

I am Using SpringBoot 2.1.4

The applications all have configured context roots.  Setting  management.endpoints.web.base-path only changes the path relative to the application context root.

Is there a way to set the management path to root when there is an application context root?  Or is there some way to hack SB2 so all requests to a path get routed to all my RequestMappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "so that PCF can access it", you mean Pivotal Apps Manager, and you are using a context path with your app then you need to apply [this workaround](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#custom-context-path).

That will allow you to use a context path with your app, but still expose the actuator endpoints so that Pivotal Apps Manager can consume them.

Hope that helps!